# What does the "p" in the first column of ls -la stand for?

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

I know about `l` (link) and `d` (directory) in the first column of the `ls -la` output.

Very recently I have seen an `p`. What does it stand for?

Example (I ommited some lines of the output as they have guid-like contents):

```
user@user-ThinkPad-T440s:~/.zoom/data$ ls -latr
[......]
prw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 Mai  2  2020 com.zoom.ipc.assistantapp__res
[......]
drwx------ 2 user user   4096 Dez  7 19:49 ConfAvatar
-rw------- 1 user user  35840 Dez  7 20:22 zoommeeting.enc.db
prw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 Dez  7 20:23 com.zoom.ipc.confapp__req
drwx------ 8 user user   4096 Dez  7 21:08 ..
prw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 Dez  7 21:08 com.zoom.ipc.confapp__res
-rw------- 1 user user 109568 Dez  7 21:08 zoomus.enc.db
prw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 Dez  7 21:08 com.zoom.ipc.assistantapp__req
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user  20480 Dez  7 21:08 .
user@user-ThinkPad-T440s:~/.zoom/data$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` stands for (named) Pipe - see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(Linux)